# Some questions on linear algebraic groups and their eigenvalues

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group (a torus, for example) of finite type over a field $K$. I have several, I suppose rather base, questions concerning the theory of such groups.

1. Suppose we fix an embedding $\iota\colon G\hookrightarrow GL_n$. In $GL_n$ we can define eigenvalues of the elements of $G$. Let us choose $g\in G$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...\lambda_n$ and we define $K_{g,\iota}$ as $K(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n)$. Does $K_{g,\iota}$ depend on $\iota$? (EDIT) It depends. But here's another conjecture. There is a "universal" embedding $u\colon G\hookrightarrow GL_n$ such that $\forall \iota\colon G\hookrightarrow GL_m$ $\forall g$ $K_{g,\iota}\subset K_{g,u}$. Perhaps this embedding is unique. Perhaps it doesn't exist but the composite of all $K_{g,\iota}$ for a fixed $g$ is finite over $K$.
2. Suppose again we have an embedding $\iota\colon G\hookrightarrow GL_n$. Then we have the determinant map $\Delta\colon GL_n\to \mathbb G_m$. Does the map $\Delta\circ\iota$ depend on the choice of $\iota$? (EDIT) It depends. Just take the tensor product of two representations. But again, perhaps there exists a universal embedding $u\hookrightarrow GL_n$ such that for all other embeddings $\iota$ $\Delta\circ\iota = (\Delta\circ u)^m$ for some $m$. Perhaps an embedding doesn't exist but still there is a homomorphism $\alpha\colon G\to \mathbb G_m$ such that $\Delta\circ\iota = \alpha^m$. (EDIT 2) As Viktor Petrov said it's not true for tori as the lattice of their one-dimensional representations can have a big rank.
3. Let $G\hookrightarrow GL_n\cong GL(V)\subset \textrm{End}(V)$ where $\textrm{End}(V)$ is a ring algebraic variety of endomorphisms of $V$. Let us call $R_\iota$ the minimal ring variety containing $G$. Does $R_\iota$ depend on the embedding?

Comment: A linear algebraic group over $k$ can be embedded in $GL_n$ over $k$ for some $n$ --- that's what linear means. The map $\Delta\circ\iota$ in 3 doesn't depend on any choices because all homomorphisms from unipotent algebraic groups to groups of multiplicative type are trivial.

Comment: And unipotent means that all eigenvalues equal 1. Thus $K_{u,\iota} = K$.

Comment: @Sasha I'm so so sorry, I meant semisimple, shame on me

Comment: @anon By a linear algebraic group I mean a group variety whose underlying algebraic variety is affine. And it's not obvious for me that linear algebraic groups defined in such a way can be embedded into $GL_n$. I forgot to say that of course I mean group varieties of finite type.

Comment: It's a standard (fairly easy) theorem that all affine algebraic groups are linear. More precisely, the regular representation contains a faithful finite-dimensional subrepresentation --- this can be proved by looking at the Hopf algebra.

Comment: I am a little confused how you can come to study semisimple linear algebraic groups without coming across the theorem mentioned by @anon above. This is covered in pretty much all books on the topic (including the three named "Linear Algebraic Groups"), and is indeed the justification for naming them "linear".

Comment: For number 3, have you tried basic examples, like the symmetric square representation of $SL_2$ into $GL_3$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I haven't studied semisimple algebraic groups, in fact, these questions came up from some differential geometric thoughts which I don't want to present here as they not at all precise. As for the fact that affine groups are linear I realized that I've proved this a lot of times but didn't realize it was a proof.

Comment: I deleted the first question about the existence of embeddings as to standard.

Comment: @Anna: At this site it's less confusing to formulate a *single question*, as stated clearly in the "help" section.      In any case your questions are all rather elementary for a research-level site.

Comment: @JimHumphreys If they're too elementary please give me the reference! I didn't find them covered in your book and I haven't managed yet to solve them by myself. And believe me, I wouldn't get an answer on StackExchange (of course, I suppose I wouldn't get it here but anyway).

Comment: Concerning point 2, you can look at 1-dimensional representations (after all, composing with $\det$ gives you a 1-dimensional representation), that are called "characters" and form a lattice. It's rather obvious that in general (say, for tori of dimension greater than 1) this lattice is not 1-dimensional, so the answer is "no".

Comment: I didn't notice that you require that the representation is faithful, but it doesn't matter much: you can always add a faithful representation into $SL_n$ that doesn't spoit the determinant.

Comment: @AnnaAbasheva the book is by James, not Jim, Humphreys.